# Не происходит перезапись поля в БД

Tags: ruby, база-данных, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!
Пишу сайт, и возникла необходимость его интернационализации. Все сделал как пишется на сайте **rusrails.ru**, но язык меняется только когда я меняю в адресной строке GET параметр **locale** из **en** на **ru**. Мне же надо, чтобы в углу страницы была ссылка на другой язык.
Немного побродя по интернетам нашел пост на сайте **stackoverflow.com**, вот ссылка - [Change locale at runtime in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822440/change-locale-at-runtime-in-rails-3).
По этому примеру сделал несколько методов у себя в контроллерах:
**ApplicationController.rb**

```
before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    if current_user
      I18n.locale = current_user.locale
    else
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end
  end
```

**UsersController.rb**

```
def change_locale
    locale = params[:locale]
    raise 'unsupported locale' unless ['ru', 'en' ].include?(locale)

    if current_user
      current_user.locale = locale
      current_user.save
    end

    I18n.locale = locale

    redirect_to :index
  end
```

Во вьюхе я вызываю метод так:

```
<%= link_to "English", :controller => 'users', :action => 'change_locale', :locale => 'en' %>
```

Все вроде бы логично и должно работать, но к сожалению работает не все. Когда юзер не аутентифицирован, то есть не залогинился, ссылка работает, и язык переключается идеально, но когда он логинится и пытается поменять язык, ничего не происходит. Я решил посмотреть сохраняется ли в БД локаль после строк:

```
if current_user
  current_user.locale = locale
  current_user.save
end
```

и заметил, что этого не происходит, почему я не знаю.
Прошу помощи у знающих. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте обновлять запись так:

**UsersController.rb**

```
private
def change_locale
    locale = params[:locale]
    raise 'unsupported locale' unless ['ru', 'en'].include?(locale)

    User.find(current_user.id).update_attribute(:locale, locale) if current_user && !current_user.blank?

    I18n.locale = locale

    redirect_to :index
end
```

Comment: ООО!!! Это просто прекрасно и как раз то что надо! Спасибо Вам большое :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Если пользователь выбрал неверную локаль, я думаю стоит возвращать не unsupported, а как минимум default_locale.
2. Как на счёт того, чтобы хранить локаль в сессии?

   ```
   def set_locale
     I18n.locale = session[:locale]
   end
   ```
3. И если всё таки нужно сохранять локаль для авторизованного пользователя, нужно удостовериться, у юзера есть такое поле.
4. В итоге я бы сделал так:

   ```
   def set_locale
     I18n.locale = current_user.locale if current_user
   end
   ```

Comment: Логинку делал по скринкастам Ryan Bates.
Вы правильно поняли, я хочу чтобы у каждого пользователя было поле в БД с его локалью, то есть чтобы когда он логинился то принималась его локаль. И самое удивительное то что это у меня работает, я это реализовал. Когда пользователь регистрируется то ему добавляется локаль, вот так:
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.locale = I18n.locale
    ...
и когда он логинится то локаль принимается так как я показал в контроллере ApplicationController.rb.
Но я не могу поменять пользователю локаль когда он уже залогинился.

Comment: А у меня как? Вы наверное не заметили что у меня эта строка есть в контроллере ApplicationController.rb, просто она обрамлена оператором if else